# Ethernet maximum current

Tags: current, ethernet, transmitter, receiver

Is there a maximum current Ethernet receivers and transmitters need to withstand? I haven't found anything regarding that topic

Comment: What do you mean by that? Are you talking about how much current the transformer coil must handle without damage?

Comment: @Justme exactly

Comment: On which side of the transformer, the chip side or the cable side? If cable side, with or without PoE support?

Comment: @Justme ideally the cable side

Comment: With PoE or without PoE?

Comment: @Justme PoE is Power over Ethernet right? Then without PoE, just data transfer

Comment: Withstand? Well, a 10/100 transceiver's consumption will not be higher than 500mW. Assuming 1:1 eth magnetics are used, I'd expect less than 100mArms.

Comment: Some of them are surge withstand capable to 6,000 volts and, that might mean a peak current of 3,000 amps on the cable side.